# c# - Remove last n elements from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How do I remove the last 2 keyValuePairs from a Dictionary of string, string where the key starts with "MyKey_" ?

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();    

myDict.Add("SomeKey1", "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("SomeKey2", "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");
```

EDIT:

```
var noGwInternal = myDict.Where(o => !o.Key.StartsWith("MyKey_")).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
var gwInternal = myDict.Where(o => o.Key.StartsWith("MyKey_")).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

How to move forward from here? Need to remove 2 of the items from gwInternal and then put noGwInternal + gwInternal into a new Dictionary together

Comment: Last, First, Next have no meaning with a Dictionary - the order is not defined

Comment: @GrantWinney I way to go would be to put all items with Keys where Key not is "MyKey_" into one new list (lisrNo1) and  Key == "MyKey_" in a new list (listNo2), then delete 2 from listNo2 thenput the remaing to  listNo1. But no idea how to do that

Comment: Look around in [Collections.Specialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized?view=netframework-4.7.1), ListDictionary and OrderedDictionary seem to be worth a check.

Comment: You just want to delete two of the `MyKey_` ones? Which two doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're trying to do (according to what you posted in your comment).

*(edit: It looks like you replaced your comment, now I'm not sure you're going for alphabetical...)*

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();    

myDict.Add("SomeKey1", "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("SomeKey2", "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_B" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_A" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");
myDict.Add("MyKey_C" + Guid.NewGuid(), "SomeValue");

var pairsToRemove = myDict.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("MyKey_"))
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
                          .Take(2);

foreach (var pair in pairsToRemove)
{
    myDict.Remove(pair.Key);
}

foreach (var pair in myDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
}
```

Output: *(MyKey_B and MyKey_C are removed)*

```
[SomeKey1, SomeValue]
[SomeKey2, SomeValue]
[MyKey_Ad6c3a25d-5d8c-44e4-9651-39164c0496fc, SomeValue]
```

I like what tevemadar mentioned about the `OrderedDictionary`... I'm not sure it'll work for what you're trying to do, but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean 'last', since this is a dictionary (there is no order), but this code will remove the last 2 in the order they were encountered in the loop.

```
List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();  
foreach(KeyValuePair pair in myDict.Reverse())
{
     if(pair.key.StartsWith("MyKey_"))
     {
           toRemove.Add(pair.key);
           toRemoveCount--;
     }

     if(toRemove.Count == 2)
     {
           break;
     }
}

foreach(string str in toRemove)
{
      myDict.Remove(str);
}
```